# How do I run an npm command inside docker from crontab?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, cron

I'm getting that it ran, but the results aren't being shown

`* * * * * docker container exec -it upvotocracy-api npm run rank`

Answer (score 0):

answer is `-it` is not needed since cron doesn't use an interactive shell or tty.

`* * * * * docker container exec upvotocracy-api npm run rank`

The above line works.